# Using Git to deploy HTML site to Apache server

Tags: git, github, deployment

I've seen articles on how to deploy to a web server using Git, but they're all far too sophisticated for me since I'm in a learning space and am simply deploying HTML files and images to a web server.

What is a simple barebones way of using Git to deploy to a server? What are the drawbacks to using the simple method? I'm just looking for a baseline here to see what the more sophisticated solutions are improving upon.

Comment: Most of the manuals use a remote repository (in an apache directory) and a post-receive hook containing `git reset --hard`, when you `git push` the remote, it  will be updated. This is the simplest scenario. By "sophisticated" you mean the SSH part? If yes, this is the only secure way to deploy with GIT to a remote server on the web.

Comment: I guess by 'sophisticated' I mean more complicated than just creating a git repo locally and pushing to master, which is what I've done so far with no need for a `post-recieve` hook or other `--hard` stuff.

Comment: The hook is needed to move the HEAD of the remote repository